# ASP.NET MVC authentication and credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a simple application in `ASP.NET MVC 5`. I'm beginner in this. The assignment is about authentication from providers(Facebook, Google, Microsoft) and displaying user credentials from provider on a web page after logging in. I did authentication successfully, but I can't figure out exactly how to get credentials and display them. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

though this is not exactly an answer, but the post is likely going to be closed. There are some nice resources in the web from which you can find some ideas, please look into the following ones:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsRyvWvo4EI&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&index=28

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxLxlukWuVg&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&index=29

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: @igortcfc instead of asking at SO why don't you check the code generated by the MVC project template? It *already* contains what you ask, with comments on how to enable each provider. You don't need a video for this